# Handling scrolling in div with display: table

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a simple header, section, footer layout for a web page. I want the header and footer to be dynamically sized, and the body to fill the remaining size of the page. That much I have so far.

My issue is handling scrollbars. Each of the three sections should maintain their own scrollbars. In no case should the whole page have a scrollbar.

What I want for the sections regarding scrollbars:

1. header

   - vertical content should just expand its height
   - horizontal content that can wrap should wrap and expand the height
   - horizontal content that can't wrap should add a horizontal scrollbar to the header
2. section

   - height should start at max, so vertical content should fill any open space or add a vertical scrollbar if there is no open space
   - horizontal content that can wrap should wrap and behave like vertical content
   - horizontal content that can't wrap should add a horizontal scrollbar to the section
3. footer

   - vertical content should just expand its height
   - horizontal content should not wrap, but rather add a horizontal scrollbar on the footer

Here is what I have so far:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
header {
    background-color: red;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
section {
    background-color: green;
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapperA {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
footer {
    background-color: blue;
}
.wrapperB {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<header>
    header
</header>
<section>
    <div class="wrapperA">
        content
    </div>
</section>
    </div>
</section>
<footer>
    <div class="wrapperB">
        footer
    </div>
</footer>
```

To demonstrate the scrollbar use, check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DeadEli/3b2fbaww/). The main issue I'm running into is that horizontal scrollbars for the whole page, rather than just the individual sections, are made when a section's content is too wide and doesn't wrap.